# Save Excel file to specific path with Django and then zip it

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have the following view which enables me to create an Excel report and then to zip it.

```
def download_report(request, slug):
    report = get_object_or_404(Report, slug=request.session['slug'])
    transporter_list = get_transporters_list_with_files(report=report.pk)
    folder = create_report_folder()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        files = []
        for transporter in transporter_list:
            reports_detail = get_object_or_404(ReportResults, report=report,
                                               transporter=get_object_or_404(Transporter, name=transporter))
            general_result_data = reports_detail.result
            weights_data = reports_detail.result_comparison_weights
            file = create_excel_report(report=report, name=transporter, folder_name=folder)
            files.append(file)

    zip_files = create_zip_files(list_files=files)
    response = serve_report_zip_file(zip_files)

    return response
```

Since multiple reports are to be generated, I'm aiming at generating all the reports and then zip them.
I created the following functions:

```
def create_report_folder():
    """
    Create a folder for the files
    """

    # Creating the folder
    random_string = get_random_string(length=10)
    folder_name = "temp" + "/" + random_string
    if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
        os.mkdir(folder_name)

    return folder_name


def create_excel_report(report, name, folder_name):
    """
       Create a downloadable report
       """
    # Getting transporters

    transporter_list = get_transporters_list_with_files(report=report.pk)

    for transporter in transporter_list:
        reports_detail = get_object_or_404(ReportResults, report=report,
                                           transporter=get_object_or_404(Transporter, name=transporter))
        general_result_data = reports_detail.result
        weights_data = reports_detail.result_comparison_weights

        general_result_data = json.loads(general_result_data)
        df_general_result = pd.DataFrame(general_result_data)
        weight_data = json.loads(weights_data)
        df_weights = pd.DataFrame(weight_data)

        # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
        folder = folder_name
        filename = "Report - " + name + ".xlsx"
        with BytesIO() as b:
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(b, engine='xlsxwriter')
            wb = writer.book

            # Sheet 1 - Report
            df_general_result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Report', index=False)
            ws = writer.sheets['Report']
            number_rows = len(df_general_result.index) + 1
            format1 = wb.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                                     'font_color': '#9C0006'})

            # Sheet 2 - Weights
            df_weights.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Weights', index=False)
            number_rows = len(df_weights.index) + 1
            ws = writer.sheets['Weights']
            format1 = wb.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                                     'font_color': '#9C0006'})

            writer.save()
            content_type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
            workbook = b.getvalue()
            print(workbook)
            response = HttpResponse(workbook, content_type=content_type)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '.xlsx"'

        return response

def create_zip_files(list_files):
    """
    Zip files
    """
    files = list_files

    # Create a ZipFile object
    for file in files:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
            with open(file, 'rb') as f:
                zf.writestr(file, f.read())
        zf.close()

    return zf


def serve_report_zip_file(file):
    """
    Serves the zip file
    """
    random_string = get_random_string(length=15)
    content_type = 'application/zip'
    response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + random_string + '.zip"'

    return response
```

I want to save the report in a specific folder and the zip all files. However, running the `create_excel_report` function, I have the following error:
`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not HttpResponse`

I tried not to use BytesIO but the Excel files ended up being corrupted... What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
Please find the traceback below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vincent/Documents/Expancy2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 472, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "/Users/vincent/Documents/Expancy2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
  File "/Users/vincent/Documents/Expancy2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 253, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(
  File "/Users/vincent/Documents/Expancy2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 435, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 408, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/vincent/Documents/Expancy2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 476, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vincent/Documents/Expancy2/src/reports/views.py", line 339, in download_report
    zip_files = create_zip_files(list_files=files)
  File "/Users/vincent/Documents/Expancy2/src/reports/helpers.py", line 456, in create_zip_files
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not HttpResponse
```

Comment: Posting the full traceback would help us identify the specific line causing the error

Comment: Hi @rayad, I just posted the full traceback!

Comment: Okay so I haven't worked with the HttpResponse o ject before. But you're trying to write the actual response object to file which you can't do. But I think you might want to do with open(zf) instead of with open(file)